# Initial select query returning result with delay in sybase

Tags: sql, select, sybase

I have a stored procedure which runs on every month end and in which we have very simple select query, but when I do call this SP facing a huge delay to retrieve the data.
When I was testing in local from the Rapid SQL client I found that the very first/initial time execution of this query it is returning the results with the delay too and consecutive executions it is returning the results faster. Below is my query in the SP. Please help.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM prechecks_data pd
INNER JOIN processing_queue tq on pd.key_id = tq.queue_id
WHERE tq.proc_status = 'PROC' AND pd.type_code = @type_id
```

Just to let you know that processing_queue columns are indexed as below
clustered, unique located on default    queue_id

nonclustered located on default proc_status

prechecks_data tables columns are not indexed anymore.

Just to let you know that processing_queue table contains data around 20,000,000 or more. Please let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: My first question is why aren't there indexes on prechecks_data if you are doing queries against it?

Comment: How many rows in `prechecks_data`?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to the fact that `prechecks` doesn't have indexes.  If you take a look at the query execution plan, it probably shows a table scan of prechecks.

If you aren't familiar with execution plans, it shows you where the server is spending the most resources while executing a query.  This link from the Sybase documentation shows how to look at the plan.

[Performance and Tuning: Using showplan](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/CACHHDHB.htm):

Comment: Hi Michael,Thanks for your response. I can have the indexes on prechecks_data table. Apart from this I suspect that the table processing_queue is having around 2MM records and even to do select count(*) from processing_queue is taking taking too long can say around few minutes. Do I need to modify the table or any other parts of it? Please help. I am not much into DB since I am java devlpr. Help here is greatly appreciated. Table is created as shown below...